# Иероглифы вместо русских букв в ActionMenu Delphi 7

Tags: кодировка, delphi-7, windows-10

Столкнулась с неприятной проблемой - на новом компьютере в Д7 в одном месте некорректно отображаются русские шрифты. Причем в самом меню буквы читаются нормально, а внутри компонента - вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект не битый - лежит в DropBox и на других ПК открывается нормально.

Что уже предпринималось:

1. Добавление недостающих шрифтов в систему (в качестве образца взят комп, на котором все работает. Система и там и там Win10)
2. Проверка установок системы - выставлен "русский" везде, где только можно
3. Переустановка дельфи.

Все пока осталось как было.

А, да, - 4. по совету гугла пыталась в реестре менять кодовую страницу с 1250 на 1251 и с 1251 на 1252 в разных комбинациях, тоже не помогло.

Что еще можно сделать?

Comment: выставлен "русский" везде, где только можно - вы точно проверяли настройку Current Language for non-Unicode programs в Region/Administrative *и* перезагружались после этого? потому что за отображение текста в вашем случае отвечает она (и только она).

Comment: Да, там стоит русский

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена установкой русской версии системы с нуля